# Appending user input to a list not working

Tags: python, input, while-loop

I am trying to take user input and append all numbers to a list. However the output I am getting just a blank list with nothing inside.

```
while True:
    my_add = input("Give me numbers and I will add them to the list. Enter 'q' to quit.")
    my_list = []
    
    if my_add == 'q':
        break
    
    else:
        my_list.append(my_add)
        
print(my_list)
```

Comment: You are doing `my_list = []` on every iteration of the loop, thus throwing away anything that was previously appended to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = []
while True:
    my_add = input("Give me numbers and I will add them to the list. Enter 'q' to quit.")
    if my_add == 'q':
        break
    else:
        my_list.append(my_add)
print(my_list)
```

`my_list` was set to empty list `[]` at every loop iteration

Answer (score 1):

Remove the variable my_list from the while loop as it is resetting on every iteration.

```
my_list = []

while True:

    my_add = input("Give me numbers and I will add them to the list. Enter 'q' to quit.")
 
    
    if my_add == 'q':
        break
    
    else:
        my_list.append(my_add)
        
print(my_list)
```